# iSCSI TGTD over InfiniBand Performance

Tags: linux, performance, iscsi, infiniband

I have just configured a server-to-server 4x SDR InfiniBand link to increase bandwidth for the backend storage of my virtual machines, specifically a database server. I am using iSCSI with TGTD on CentOS 6 and I am able to achieve about 6.45Gbps using IPoIB when testing with iperf.

I have managed to tune the iSCSI initiator and target to the point where I can achieve about 260MB/s write to an SSD. However, this is still not an optimal write speed given I can write at about 500-600MB/s locally.

The parameters I am currently using are:

- MaxRecvDataSegmentLength 4194304
- MaxXmitDataSegmentLength 524288
- MaxBurstLength 4194304
- FirstBurstLength 262144
- MaxOutstandingUnexpectedPDUs=0
- MaxOutstandingR2T=1
- MaxCommands=256
- QueueDepth=128

Has anyone had any experience in tuning this? Is it possible to get any higher than this with configuration changes? Even by doing a RAID 0 on two devices, I can still only achieve the same bandwidth, which I would have expected higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results you got are reasonably expectable with current setup.
You can get additional perfomance gain with `iser` transport mode.

Configuration tips from [README.iser](https://github.com/fujita/tgt/blob/master/doc/README.iser)

Target:

```
    ./tgtadm --lld iser --mode target \
             --op new --tid 1 --targetname "iqn.$(hostname).t1"
    ./tgtadm --lld iser --mode target \
             --op bind --tid 1 --initiator-address ALL
    ./tgtadm --lld iser --mode logicalunit \
             --op new --tid 1 --lun 1 \ --backing-store /dev/sde
             --bstype rdwr
```

Initiator:

```
    iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p $targe
    iscsiadm -m node -p $targetip -T $targetname --op update \
        -n node.transport_name -v iser
    iscsiadm -m node -p $targetip -T $targetname --login
```

Related usefull SF question: [Set up simple Infiniband Block Storage (SRP or iSER)](https://serverfault.com/questions/327947/set-up-simple-infiniband-block-storage-srp-or-iser).

Comment: I have changed the transport mode to 'iser' but do not seem to notice much difference, however there may be a few added MB/s which I'm just not noticing due to the inconsistent results. From some further testing, it almost seems like iSCSI is ignoring my MTU of 65520 (for Infiniband).

Comment: I checked out the article you posted... I'm thinking I might need to re-implement this using SRP to get better performance instead of IPoIB. Thank you for your advice! :)