# Set up Windows 10 SRP initiator

Tags: windows, ubuntu, infiniband, rdma

How do can I setup an SRP Windows 10 initiator? I've seen several mentions of an initiator being included in WinOF but I haven't found any instructions on *how* to do it.

The initiator will be Windows 10 Pro with a Connect-X2 DDR interface. I have WinOF 5.50.50000.0 installed.
The target will be Ubuntu 18.04 with a Connect-X3 FDR10 interface.

An anser from [this question from 2011](https://serverfault.com/q/327947/295740) there is no iSER initiator for Windows...though, if one has been added that would be okay. As would NVMe-OF

I would prefer to be able to use SRP/iSER/NVMe-OF vs. iSCSI since Windows removed RC mode from IPoIB (on my computer IPoIB caps out at a few Gb/s.

Answer (score 2):

StarWind has Windows iSER and NVMeoF initiators for sure, but I don't know are they public ones, or proprietary user land code using inside their target products. It worth contacting them directly and asking IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of WinOF include an SRP initiator. See also https://downloads.openfabrics.org/Windows/. Unfortunately the most recent release of that project was a while ago (2013).